# The fastest way to apply function to matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have Nx2 matrix `A` and a function `f` of 2 variables.

```
A = [1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8;9,0];
func = '@(x1, x2) sin(x1+x2)*cos(x1*x2)/(x1-x2)';
func = str2func(func);
```

I can apply function to matrix in a way like this:

```
values = arrayfun(@(x1,x2) func(x1, x2), A(:,1), A(:,2));
```

It seems to be faster than by `for-loop`, but still to slow for my program.
I wonder if there is any other way to do it faster?

**Edit.** Functions are generated by the program. They are made by some simple functions like plus, minus, times, expl, ln. I don't know how to vectorize them.

Comment: The fastest is to _vectorize_ your function, if possible. What is the exact function? Is it the one in your example?

Comment: @LuisMendo my functions are generated by my program. They are made by some simple functions like plus, minus, times, expl, ln.

Comment: If you only use those simple functions, simply using `.*`, `./`, `.^` may achieve vectorization

Comment: The string is not necessary in `func = '@(x1, x2) sin(x1+x2)*cos(x1*x2)/(x1-x2)'`. It is actually possible to create a function handle as `func = '@(x1, x2) sin(x1+x2)*cos(x1*x2)/(x1-x2)` and do function calls `func(a,b)`.

Comment: @restrest: As LuisMendo and patrik already mentioned: Do avoid string representations of functions and `str2func` like the plague. If for some reason this isn't an option (which I don't think is possible), you could have a look at [vectorize](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest approach is to [**vectorize**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) your function, if that's possible. Vectorizing can sometimes be done by just changing `*`, `/`, `^` into their element-wise versions `.*`, `./`, `.^`. In other cases it may require use of [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

For your example function, vectorization is straightforward:

```
A = [1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8;9,0];
x1 = A(:,1);
x2 = A(:,2);
values = sin(x1+x2).*cos(x1.*x2)./(x1-x2);
```